# Trying to call Google Calendar API (using gcsa) on Google Colab but credentials path is incorrect

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-calendar-api, gcsa

I am writing a Python script which calls the Google Calendar API so that I can create an event in my Google Calendar. It was a nightmare to set up the calendar API using the official documentation so I am using gcsa (Google Calendar Simple API). I have the event creation script in my Google Drive mounted on Colab. However, the `credentials.json` can't be found.

I used:

```
gc = GoogleCalendar(credentials_path='content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/credentials.json')
```

to specify the path to the `credentials.json` file that I downloaded from my Google Workspace. The default path of `root/.credentials/` does not work in Google Colab (but it works on my laptop). These are the error messages I get. What should I do?

```
   gc = GoogleCalendar(credentials_path='content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/credentials.json')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gcsa/google_calendar.py", line 62, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gcsa/_services/base_service.py", line 18, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gcsa/_services/authentication.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.credentials = self._get_credentials(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gcsa/_services/authentication.py", line 101, in _get_credentials
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials_path, scopes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 204, in from_client_secrets_file
    with open(client_secrets_file, "r") as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/credentials.json'
```

Comment: Hey, it seems like the formatting is messing with your code. Surround the code with \`\`\` on the top and bottom to make the question easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, really new to this! I hope that's better now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it! From gcsa documentation on Token object, I used:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials 

token = Credentials(
token='<access_token>',
refresh_token='<refresh_token>',
client_id='<client_id>',
client_secret='<client_secret>',
scopes=['googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
token_uri='oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
)
gc = GoogleCalendar(credentials=token)
```

I took the parameters from token.json which was generated when I ran the code on my laptop. I'm glad it works now! :)

But is this the right way to do it? How long will the token last until I have to get a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is just the file path. If your drive is mounted, you should  be able to use the relative path from `'content'`

```
gc = GoogleCalendar(credentials_path='drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/credentials.json') # without content/
```

or absolute path:

```
gc = GoogleCalendar(credentials_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/credentials.json') # with / at the start
```

---

As for "*How long will the token last until I have to get a new one?*", you might run into [this issue](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api/issues/118).

---

I'm the author of the library BTW, reach out if you feel like documentation might use some clarification.